# Можно ли написать cron, чтобы он запускал скрипт с 10:00 до 21:00. каждый час?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, надо написать cron чтобы запускал скрипт каждый час но чтобы работал с 9:00 по 21:00 МСК. Как это можно сделать и можно ли вообще ?

Или есть другой вариант ?

Comment: Можно. В документации это есть

Comment: Я написал каждый час: 0 */1 * * * 
но не могу понять как сделать промежуток

Comment: Рекомендую https://crontab.guru/

Answer (score 3):

Настроил, вдруг кому поможет:

```
0 10-21 * * * command
```

https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=crontab&category=5&russian=0

> Допустимо указание нескольких значений (и диапазонов через тире) через запятую. Примеры: `1,2,5,9` `0-4,8-12`